# Recursive martingale

Tags: convergence-divergence, stochastic-processes, conditional-expectation, martingales

> Let $X_0=x_o \in [0,1]$ and $(X_n)_n$ a stoch. process s.t
>
> $X_{n+1}= $$\begin{cases}
> \frac{1}{2} + \frac{X_n}{2}, \quad \text{with prob. } X_n \\
> \frac{X_n}{2},\quad \text{with prob. } 1-X_n
> \end{cases} $
>
> Prove:
>
> i)$(X_n)_n$ is a martingale
>
> ii) $(X_n)_n$ converges almost surely

---

i) I consider the natural filtration $F_n= \sigma (X_1, \ldots, X_n)$. By definition, $X_n$ is $F_n$ adapted for every $n$.

I check the martingale property: $E[X_{n+1}|F_n]$. But in the expression of $X_{n+1}$ I have just terms with $X_n$, which I know since I am conditioned to $F_n$, i.e. I know all the values, so $X_{n+1}$ is $F_n$ measurable and hence $E[X_{n+1}|F_n]=E[X_{n+1}]=\frac{X_n}{2}+\frac{X_n^2}{2}+\frac{X_n}{2}-\frac{X_n^2}{2}=X_n$.

ii) I think I have the apply the "martingale convergence thm". More specifically, I need to check that

\begin{align}
\sup_n E[|X_n|] < \infty
\end{align}

in order to conclude that $X_n$ converge a.s. to a $F_{\infty}$-measurable r.v. $X$

Now, 
\begin{align}
E[|X_{n+1}|]=|\frac{1+X_n}{2}|X_n + \frac{|X_n|}{2}(1-X_n), \quad \star
\end{align}
and I'd like to show it's bounded. The key point is (I guess) to find the recurrence relation between $X_{n+1}$ and $X_0=x_0 \in [0,1]$, but I can't see it (in particular for the first term).

I found the relations:

$\bullet$ $X_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}+ \frac{1}{2^n}+\frac{1+x_0}{2^{n+1}}$ with prob. $\frac{x_0}{2^n}$

$\bullet$ $X_{n+1}=\frac{x_0}{2^{n+1}}$, with prob. $1 - \frac{x_0}{2^n}$

and so each one of the summand in $\star$ is bounded, so the supremum over $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is also bounded, hence by the martingale convergence theorem applies.

Is everything okay?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are skipping some non-trivial steps here. First, it is not readily apparent that $X_n$ is integrable. From the definition of $X_1$, we see that its minimum value is zero (attained at $x_0=0$ with probability one) and its maximum value is one (attained at $x_0=1$ with probability one). Then, assuming $0\leqslant X_n\leqslant 1$, we have by a similar argument that $0\leqslant X_n\leqslant1$, so by induction $0\leqslant X_n\leqslant 1$ for all $n$. It follows then that
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[|X_n|] &= \mathbb E[X_n]\\
&= (1/2 + X_n/2)X_n + X_n/2(1-X_n)\\ &\leqslant (1/2+1/2)\cdot 1 + 1/2\cdot 1\\ &= 5/2\\&<\infty.
\end{align}

Your verification of the martingale property is correct.

As for convergence, I believe my argument above suffices for Doob's martingale convergence theorem. (Technically the condition is $\sup_n \mathbb E[X_n^-]<\infty$ but $\mathbb P(X_n\geqslant0)$ here so we need not consider the negative part of $X_n$.)

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler approach: verify by induction that $0\leq X_n \leq 1$ for all $n$. Obviously this implies a.s. convergence.

Comment: thanks! The law of the limit of $X_n$ can be computed by recurrence, right?

Comment: The limiting r.v. takes only the value $0$ and $1$ because $X=\frac X 2$ or $X=\frac {1+X} 2$.  Now $EX_n=x_0$ for all $n$ so $EX=x_0$. This means $X$ takes the value $1$ with porbability $x_0$ and the value $0$ with probability $1-x_0$.

Comment: How can you see that $E[X_n]=x_0$? It's not clear to me

Comment: @serpa If $\{X_n\}$ is a martingale then $EX_n$ does not depend on $n$. This is immediate from the definition of a martingale. In this case $X_0=x_0$ so $EX_n=x_0$ for all $n$.

Comment: Oh right. Last thing: why from the fact that it has constant expectation you conclude that $X$ takes *just* the values $0$ and $1$?

Comment: @serpa $X_{n+1}= \frac {X_n} 2$ or $X_{n+1}= \frac {1+X_n} 2$. Since $X_n \to $X almost surely we see that $X= \frac X 2$ or $X= \frac {1+X} 2$. The first equation implies $X=0$ and the second one implies $X=1$.

Comment: Perfect, thanks

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I believe I verified this in my answer, no?